# Resample df to smaller time steps and average the counts

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, resampling

I have a dataframe containing counts over time periods (rainfall in periods of 3 hours), something like this:

```
time_stamp,           rain_fall_in_mm
2019-01-01 00:03:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:06:00,  3.9
2019-01-01 00:09:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:12:00,  1.2
```

I need to upsample the dataframe into time periods of 1 hour and I would like to average out the counts for the rain, so that there are no NaNs and the total sum of rain remains the same, means this is the desired result:

```
time_stamp,           rain_fall_in_mm
2019-01-01 00:01:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:02:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:03:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:04:00,  1.3
2019-01-01 00:05:00,  1.3
2019-01-01 00:06:00,  1.3
2019-01-01 00:07:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:08:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:09:00,  0.0
2019-01-01 00:10:00,  0.4
2019-01-01 00:11:00,  0.4
2019-01-01 00:12:00,  0.4
```

I found that I can do something like `series.resample('1H').bfill()` or `series.resample('1H').pad()`. These solve the resampling issue, but don't fulfil the desired averaging. Do you have any suggestions what to do? Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure that your index is in datetime format. If it is not you can do this in the following way:

```
df.set_index(pd.date_range(start=df.time_stamp[0], periods=len(df), freq='3H'), inplace=True)
```

Then use this if want to upscale only the one column

```
df_rain_hourly_column = df.resample('H').bfill().rain / 3.
```

If your initial `df` contains only floats you can operate on the whole dataframe

```
df2 = df.resample('H').bfill() / 3.
```

The division by `3.` (the length factor of old_time_period/new_time_period) is a bit hacky, but I really haven't found a more general and simple solution anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df2 = df.reindex(pd.date_range(start = '1/1/2019',periods = 13,freq='1min'))
df2.fillna(0).groupby((~df2['rain_fall_in_mm'].isna()).iloc[::-1].cumsum()).transform('mean')
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It creates a `df2` with the correct intervals, but `df2` is containing only NaNs. But thanks anyway! Can you give it another try?

Comment: is your index set as a datetime index?

Comment: You were right about my index, it was not in datetime. I corrected it, but now I get NaNs again for the newly created intermediate rows. I found an easier solution: `df_rain_hourly_column = df.resample('H').bfill().rain / 3.` But thanks for your post, I will vote it up! If you know how to still rectify it, let me know!